# How do I install and import the Powershell Community Extensions for a normal user?

Tags: powershell

I want to use Powershell as my Visual Studio Command Prompt and have found that the route to doing this is via the Powershell Community Extensions but I am having trouble installing and importing Pscx.

From a normal (i.e. not run as Administrator) Powershell prompt; if I run `Install-Module Pscx` I get the error

> Administrator rights are required to install modules in 'C:\Program
>   Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules'. Log on to the computer with an
>   account that has Administrator rights, and then try again, or install
>   'D:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules' by adding "-Scope
>   CurrentUser" to your command. You can also try running the Windows
>   PowerShell session with elevated rights (Run as Administrator).

I took the suggestion and tried running `Install-Module Pscx -Scope CurrentUser`, which reported no errors. But then when I run `Import-Module Pscx` I get the error

> The specified module 'Pscx' was not loaded because no valid module
>   file was found in any module directory.

After running `Remove-Module Pscx` I ran a Powershell prompt as administrator where I was able to install and import Pscx but having done so I can still not import it from a non-admin Powershell prompt. My final attempt was (in the admin prompt) to remove the module and install it again with `-Scope AllUsers` but this still gives the same error when I try to `Import-Module Pscx` in a non-admin prompt.

I have been a developer for 30+ years but every time I try to do something in Powershell it makes me feel stupid. Despite all the great documentation, I just don't find it easy to use. Can someone please help me get past this current misery. I don't just want to solve the problem but also try to understand what is happening in the hope it that it will help me reach that place where I can actually understand why Powershell is behaving in a seemingly strange manner that makes little sense to me.

My version of Powershell is 5.0, build 10586, revision 494.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured out what the problem was.

`Install-Module` with `-Scope CurrentUser` installs the module in the `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules` folder but this folder is not included in the PSModulePath environment variable, hence `Import-Module` can't find the module. Once I figured this out I add the following to my profile so I won't be caught out by this again.

```
if ($env:PSModulePath -notlike "*D:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules*")
{
  $env:PSModulePath = $env:PSModulePath + ";D:\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules"
}
```

Notice that while my `%USERPROFILE%` is `C:\Users\SteveC` I have moved my Documents folder from my SSD C drive to my HDD D drive so `%USERPROFILE%\Documents` resolves to `D:\Documents`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Download Pscx package from CodePlex
2. Paste the unzipped Pscx in C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules
3. Open Powershell Editor ISE as Administrator
4. Run `Install-Module Pscx -AllowClobber`
5. Done